# digest too big for rsa key

Tags: node.js, jwt

I want to implement jwt authorization in my node js project following  this [post](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e)

I have installed

```
 $ npm install jsonwebtoken
```

And in my code I have

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const payload = somedata;
var privateKEY  = fs.readFileSync('../Keys/private.key', 'utf8');
onst token = jwt.sign({ payload }, privateKEY/*config.auth.jwt_secret*/, { expiresIn: '1d', algorithm: 'RS512' });
```

And when I run this script I get the following error

```
 error:04075070:rsa routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa key
```

My private key I have generated using [this](http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/) tool with 512 bit.
I have also tried to change `RS512` to `RS256` and it worked normally, but in this case I was unable to verify the token.

What causes this error?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to verify the token? I had to revert to RSA 256 and it encrypts/decrypts just fine

Comment: Same issue here, except that RS256 doesn't work either.

Comment: Hey I am facing with the same problem. Have you found a solution? Can you please write?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by updating keysize for the private key. I am also not good in cryptography but as I understand this https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/739 issue. They keysize of your private key should be a minimum of 2048 bits.

Below is the command to generate RSA private key with keysize `2048` bit.

```bash
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
```

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const payload = somedata;
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('private.key', 'utf8');
onst token = jwt.sign({ payload }, privateKey, { expiresIn: '1d', algorithm: 'RS512' });
```

```bash
# extra information
# generate public key from above private.key
openssl rsa -in private.key -outform PEM -pubout -out public.key
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the exact same problem.  Changing the algorithm in the options to '**HS512**' fixed it.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const payload = somedata;
var privateKEY  = fs.readFileSync('../Keys/private.key', 'utf8');
const token = jwt.sign({ payload }, privateKEY/*config.auth.jwt_secret*/, { expiresIn: '1d', algorithm: 'HS512' });
```

Comment: HMAC signs with symmetric keys, which kind of defeat the purposes of using RSA keys in the first place.